# Unable to store the depth map in 32FC1 format?

Tags: ros, cv-bridge, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I want to get the depth data from Creative 3d Senz camera. I am not able to store the depth map in its correct format. Please see the snippet below.

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2 
  3 import sys
  4 import cv2
  5 import rospy
  6 from std_msgs.msg import String
  7 from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
  8 from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2
  9 from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

 10 
 11 class ImgCapture:
 12     def __init__(self):
 13         self.CvImg = CvBridge()
 14         skImg = rospy.Subscriber("/softkinetic_camera/rgb/image_color",Image, self.callbackImg)  
 15         skDep = rospy.Subscriber("/softkinetic_camera/depth/image_raw",Image, self.callbackDepth)
 16 
 17     def callbackImg(self, data):
 18         #print "Processing RGB"
 19         try:
 20               NewImg = self.CvImg.imgmsg_to_cv2(data,"bgr8")
 21               print data.encoding
 22               print
 23               cv2.imwrite("rgb.png", NewImg)
 24         except CvBridgeError as e:
 25               print(e)
 26 
 27     def callbackDepth(self, data):
 28         #print "Depth"
 29         try:
               # THIS LINE GIVES ME THE FOLLOWING ERROR
 30           NewImg = self.CvImg.imgmsg_to_cv2(data,"32FC1")                           
 31           print data.encoding
 32           print
 33           cv2.imwrite("depth.png", NewImg)
 34         except CvBridgeError as e:
 35           print(e)
 36
```

In the above code snippet, callbackDepth() gives me the following error:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1487855299.273887] bad callback: <bound method ImgCapture.callbackDepth of <__main__.ImgCapture instance at 0x7fc64712e320>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 720, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/lerrel/ros_ws/src/baxter_examples/scripts/image_capture.py", line 33, in callbackDepth
    cv2.imwrite("depth.png", NewImg)
TypeError: img data type = 14 is not supported
```

If I change line 30. to      `30           NewImg = self.CvImg.imgmsg_to_cv2(data,"passthrough")` , here is no error but the image saved is just black with no depth information.

Can you please help me understand what is going wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255413/unable-to-store-the-depth-map-in-32fc1-format?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay so here it goes!
I followed the solution by @E1000ii [given here](http://answers.ros.org/question/58902/how-to-store-the-depth-data-from-kinectcameradepth_registreredimage_raw-as-gray-scale-image/)  and it worked

I am copy-pasting my changed code, based on the solution provided above:

```
def callbackDepth(self, data):
    print "all is well"
    try:
        NewImg = self.CvImg.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "passthrough")
        depth_array = np.array(NewImg, dtype=np.float32)
        cv2.normalize(depth_array, depth_array, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        print data.encoding
        print
        cv2.imwrite("depth.png", depth_array*255)
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)
```

---

Originally posted by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) with karma: 112 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0